# Mysql find the range with most elements

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a simple mysql table with name and age columns. I need to find the age range (say with length 5) which contains the most number of records. Please note that the range can be from anything to anything (like 1 to 5 years or 2 to 6 years). I have created a sqlfiddle for the same at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a65265/1

I have tried using DIV and searched through the forums, but the closest i can get is predefined ranges like age 5-10, 10-15 etc. I need a more generic solution for all possible age ranges.

Comment: What exactly is age range with length 5?

Comment: any range of length 5. sorry, didnt know how to put it. for  example age 0-5, 1-6, 2-7 etc

Comment: @Mihai: It sounds like he wants all ranges of 5 from 1 to `MAX(age)`.  How ever many that is.

Comment: @RocketHazmat - yes, thats correct, thanks

Comment: Would that http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a65265/2 solve your problem?

Comment: @JorgeCampos: He wants to see which range (1->5, 2->6, 3->7, ... , `MAX(age)-4` -> `MAX(age)`) has the most records.

Comment: @JorgeCampos - sorry, no. what i  need is the range which has the most number of  records. In this case, one  of the right answers would  be 18-22 range which has 6 records

Comment: @Mihai - no, this is heavily redacted and i do have primary keys on the original table. i have tried to get the gist  of  the problem to make it more  generic

Comment: Oww I get it. Sorry, the query to solve that will be a little more complicated, you have to find the ranges first and from then count it.

Comment: what code have you attempted to use to answer your question?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
select      5 *  floor((t.age-o.offset)/5)      + o.offset      as from_age 
           ,5 * (floor((t.age-o.offset)/5) + 1) + o.offset - 1  as to_age
           ,count(*)                                            as cnt


from                    test as t 

            cross join (           select 0  as offset 
                        union all  select 1 
                        union all  select 2 
                        union all  select 3 
                        union all  select 4
                        ) as o

group by    o.offset 
           ,floor((t.age-o.offset)/5)

order by    cnt desc

limit       1
```

---

The basic idea -
Each row is being duplicated 5 times, with offset in the range of 0 to 4.
Each offset is causing a different distribution of the elements as described in the following diagrams:

```
x:                0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
                  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
                  -------------  -------------  -------------  -------------
floor((x-0)/5):   0              1              2              3 


x:                0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
                  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
                  -  -------------  -------------  -------------  -------------
floor((x-1)/5):      0              1              2              3 


x:                0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
                  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
                  ----  -------------  -------------  -------------  -------------
floor((x-2)/5):         0              1              2              3 


x:                0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
                  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
                  -------  -------------  -------------  -------------  -------------
floor((x-3)/5):            0              1              2              3 


x:                0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19
                  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
                  ----------  -------------  -------------  -------------  -------------
floor((x-4)/5):               0              1              2              3
```

Comment: wow. i am still trying to understand the query :). many thanks. much appreciated.

Comment: care to explain how this works?

Comment: @DForck42, see edited answer.

Comment: @pinaki, see edited answer.

Comment: excellent, thank you!  I was going to write almost this exact query as an answer

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz - thanks for that :). cheers