# Finding the range with most rows MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table that holds prices. The idea behind this is to have users suggest prices that they think are reasonable for a good. So for example, lets say I have a table name `tbl_Prices`:

```
| id |price |
|1   |1200  |
|2   |50000 |
|3   |50000 |
|4   |45000 |
|5   |506980|
|6   |2000  |
```

From this table we can see that the range with most rows is `50000 to 506980`. 
So I was hoping to come up with a query that finds this range.

I looked at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40617497/mysql-find-the-range-with-most-elements). It's pretty good, but for some reasons, I cannot increase the offset, I can barely understand what is happening, it yields:

```
|from_price|to_price|count|
|499999    | 500003 |2    |
|499998    | 500002 |2    |
|499997    | 500001 |2    |
|499996    | 500000 |2    |
|500000    | 500004 |2    |
|499996    | 450000 |1    |
```

Comment: Please post textual data instead of images

Comment: I will take note of that next time, i just thought it would be neater using an image

Comment: Please do it in this question

Comment: A minute please

Comment: I have added the textual data

Comment: Seems like [you asked this question before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41327745/finding-most-common-range-of-numbers) with an accepted answer!

Comment: @Sepehr yes i did, wanted to delete it because i did not phrase my question right, couldnt because it had an answer so i flagged it.

Answer (score 0):

I have figure out the solution to find out the total as per range defined as below:

```
SELECT
CASE WHEN accountid BETWEEN 0 AND 216 THEN '0 to 216'
WHEN accountid BETWEEN 217 and 319 THEN '217 to 319'
WHEN accountid BETWEEN 320 and 429 THEN '320 to 429'
WHEN accountid BETWEEN 430 and 539 THEN '430 to 539'
WHEN accountid BETWEEN 540 and 649 THEN '540 to 649'
WHEN accountid BETWEEN 650 and 759 THEN '650 to 759'
WHEN accountid >= 860 THEN '860 +' END AS accountgroup, count(accountid) AS total
FROM account
GROUP BY accountgroup;
```

Output is as below:

[image]

Hope it will help. Thanks.

Comment: In this case you have two write 2 queries... in first query try to find out the range and in second query build a case query using my solution. I dont think there will be any issue to find the ranges.

Comment: Please try to get min and max value from table.. and set the interval by calculating the difference.. so your range will be look like min-interval, interval-max and use this range in second query. Best luck. Thanks